# Cancel function if input search-box is empty

Tags: javascript, search-box

I have this code:

```
function buscar() {
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
input = document.getElementById("searchinput");
filter = accent_fold(input.value).toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("CSVTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var matching = false;
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    if (td) {
        if (accent_fold(td.innerHTML).toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            matching = true;
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

if (matching) {
    $('#CSVTable').css('display', 'block');
    $('#no-results').css('display', 'none');
} else {
    $('#CSVTable').css('display', 'none');
    $('#no-results').css('display', 'block');
}
```

}

Linked with this

```
        <div id="buscador">
        <input type="text" id="searchinput" onsearch="buscar()" placeholder="Cercar per cognom"/>
        <span class="buscador-btn">
            <button class="btns" type="submit" id="searchbutton" onclick="buscar(); showDiv();">
                <span style="font-size: 15px; color: White;">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </span><b>Cercar</b>
            </button>
            <button class="btnc" onclick="document.getElementById('searchinput').value = '' ; hideDiv();">
                <span style="font-size: 15px; color: Red;">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </span><b>Esborrar</b>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

How to implement a script that, if, when click on search button and the searchinput is empty change its own `placeholder=""` to warn that there is no text introduced to search? If not, continue with the script to search.

Thanks

CODE UPDATED TO THIS. Working but the return false don't stop the script:

var input = document.getElementById("searchinput");
    if(input.value.trim().length){

```
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
input = document.getElementById("searchinput");
filter = accent_fold(input.value).toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("CSVTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var matching = false;
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    if (td) {
        if (accent_fold(td.innerHTML).toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            matching = true;
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

if (matching) {
    $('#CSVTable').css('display', 'block');
    $('#no-results').css('display', 'none');
} else {
    $('#CSVTable').css('display', 'none');
    $('#no-results').css('display', 'block');
}

}else{
input.placeholder="vacío";
return false;
}
```

}

Comment: When it should verify if it's empty?

Comment: Hi, @mdomfu, welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: When click on button id="searchinput"

Comment: I try this but no luck: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_validation_empty_input

Comment: Code updated, not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to go about this. One way can be by validating the input field when the form is submitted. This seems to be what you were going for.

The approach I used, is to place the `<input>` field inside a `<form>` element and call a function `checkForm` to verify it's not empty, if it's not empty you can call your `buscar` function there.

[Here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/jmmarco/uojy5bds/17/)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to simply change the `placeholder`attribute if validation failed.

For jquery is `$(your selector).attr("placeholder", "Type name here..")`;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "" || x == null) {
   document.getElementById("searchbox").placeholder = "Type name here..";
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" required>
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="searchbox">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it adapted to the code inside the div

Answer (score 0):

Sir you want to change the placeholder of the search-box if input is empty?

also it's better to change `<input type="search"`if you want to use `onsearch=""` in your `searchinput`

```js
function validateSearchbox() {
  var input = document.getElementById("searchinput");
  if(input.value.trim().length){
   // the search-box is not empty
    // run buscar...
   buscar();
  }else{
   // search-box is empty
   console.log("no input");
    // change place holder to empty or change it to anything you like
    input.placeholder=""; 
  }
}

function buscar() {
 console.log("buscar running");
  // insert buscar code here
}
```

```html
<div id="buscador">
  <input type="search" id="searchinput" onsearch="validateSearchbox()" placeholder="Cercar per cognom"/>
  <span class="buscador-btn">
    <button class="btns" type="submit" id="searchbutton" onclick="validateSearchbox()">
      <span style="font-size: 15px; color: White;">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </span><b>Cercar</b>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working. What I need is implement a placeholder change if the imputbox is empty when click on the search button. If its empty, change it, if contains data to search, run the function buscar()

Comment: let me clarify this. you want to have a "function to validate" the search-box to determine if it's empty. and if search-box is not empty you want to call buscar()?

Comment: Yes, this can be another option. The function to validate needs to be change de placeholder.

Comment: @mdomfu I updated the code, I added function to validate.